# Windows 2003 Domain Controller Very Upset about NIC Teaming

Tags: windows, active-directory, bonding

I set up BACS (Broadcom Teaming) to team two NIC on a Windows 2003 Active Directory Domain Controller.  Networking still works okay, I can ping the gateway etc, but both DNS and Active Directory fail to start with various 40xx errors.

The team that I created is Smart load Balancing with Failover, with one backup and only one in smart load balancing (So really it is just failover).  I have the team the same IP address that the single active NIC had before.

Anyone seen this before, or have any ideas what the problem might be?

```
Event Type: Error
Event Source:   DNS
Event Category: None
Event ID:   4015
Date:       3/7/2010
Time:       10:33:03 AM
User:       N/A
Computer:   ADC
Description:
The DNS server has encountered a critical error from the Active Directory. 
Check that the Active Directory is functioning properly. The extended error debug
information (which may be empty) is "". The event data contains the error.

Event Type: Error
Event Source:   DNS
Event Category: None
Event ID:   4004
Date:       3/7/2010
Time:       10:33:03 AM
User:       N/A
Computer:   ADC
Description:
The DNS server was unable to complete directory service enumeration of zone ..  
This DNS server is configured to use information obtained from Active Directory for 
this zone and is unable to load the zone without it.  Check that the Active Directory
is functioning properly and repeat enumeration of the zone. The extended error debug
information (which may be empty) is "". The event data contains the error.

Event Type: Error
Event Source:   NTDS Replication
Event Category: DS RPC Client 
Event ID:   2087
Date:       3/7/2010
Time:       10:40:28 AM
User:       NT AUTHORITY\ANONYMOUS LOGON
Computer:   ADC
Description:
Active Directory could not resolve the following DNS host name of the source domain controller to an IP address. This error prevents additions, deletions and changes in 
Active Directory from replicating between one or more domain controllers in the forest. 
Security groups, group policy, users and computers and their passwords will be 
inconsistent between domain controllers until this error is resolved, potentially 
affecting logon authentication and access to network resources.
```

Comment: What exactly makes you think it is the teaming that causes DNS and AD trouble? You're sure it is related?

Comment: Including some of the errors may be helpful.

Comment: icky2000: When I created the team and then rebooted, AD and DNS stopped working (but networking was fine).  When I removed the team and rebooted, AD and DNS started working again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Historically I've had nothing but trouble from Broadcom NICs, but I don't think that's your problem here.  What I think is your problem is that your AD and DNS services are coming up *before* your NIC teaming service does, and are therefore seeing a network configuration that's not valid.

Comment: Is there a way to change it so the NICs come up first?

Comment: You could probably create a dependency in HKLM\System\CurrentControlSet\Services\servicename - have a look at something like winmgmt to get the format required.  It should be enough to do it for the DNS server as AD will in turn have a dependency on that.

Comment: mh: Ah, thanks, will try that next time I get a Window.  This sounds like a promising solution....